# How to change ViewController after rest api called

Tags: swift

I build this code to call rest api using swift.
Now if the rest api responde as success message I need to change View Controllery automatically without click by user.

So this is my method:

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textViewName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textViewSurname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textViewEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textViewPhone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textViewPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textViewConfirmPassword: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    @IBAction func registerUser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let name = textViewName.text;
        let surname = textViewSurname.text;
        let email = textViewEmail.text;
        let phone = textViewPhone.text;
        let password = textViewPassword.text;
        let confirmPassword = textViewPassword.text;
        var user = UserModel(first_name: name,
                             last_name: surname,
                             type: "user",
                             password: password,
                             email: email,
                             phone: phone,
                             category_id: "0",
                             address: "",
                             lat: "",
                             lon: "",
                             description: "",
                             store_address: "",
                             zipcode: "",
                             register_id: ""
                             )
        
       
        let postUrl = APIRequest2(endPoint: "signup_rest")
        postUrl.signup(user: user, completition: { result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let message):
                print ("Messaggio dal server: \(message.status)")
                let newViewController = FirstViewController()
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)

            //self.showToast(message: "Registrazione avvenuta con successo.", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error as occured\(error)")
            }
            })
        
    }
```

So If I receive success message, I should to change view in FirstViewController.
If I try to execute this code I receive the follow error message:

```
[UIViewController init] must be used from main thread only
UIViewController.navigationController must be used from main thread only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
   let newViewController = FirstViewController()
   self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```